# How can I use rsync over AFP and SMB protocols?

Tags: rsync, smb

I have a Lacie CloudBox NAS drive. I can acces the folders with no problems via the file explorer, however I would like to use rsync to sync some files. I have used rsync before to sync folders on a USB drive with no hassles.

I want so do something like this:

```
rsync -a /home/myuser/folder_to_sync nas_folder
```

what should I write instead of "nas_folder"?

The NAS automatically creates a folder called Family which can be accessed anonymously. If I navigate to it and click "Properties", its location is

```
afp://anonymous@mynas.local/Family/
```

However if I create a password protected user in the NAS, the location of its folder is:

```
smb://mynnas.local:139/user_with_pwd/
```

How can I use rsync in each case?